# While downloading files using MIME the file Name with non-english characters are not getting downloaded in .Net

Tags: c#, zip, mime

Hi When I am trying to download multiple files and zipping it in one zip file the file with non-english name is not coming all other files gets downloaded except that one file .
File Name :答复정리答复정리.txt
In zip all other files are present but except this one

```
long[] fileIds = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<long[]>(fileIdsStr);
string[] FileNames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(FileNamesStr);
ZipOutputStream zipMemoryStream1 = new ZipOutputStream(Response.OutputStream);
int chunkSize = 1024;
string contentType = MimeMapping.GetMimeMapping("download_zip.zip");
foreach (long fileId in fileIds)
{
    string fs_FileName = fs_FileNames[count];
    string fileData = this.getFileData(fileId);
    
    var bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(fileData);

    var file = new ZipEntry(fs_FileName);
    zipMemoryStream1.PutNextEntry(file);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[chunkSize];
    zipMemoryStream1.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    count++;
}

var cd = new System.Net.Mime.ContentDisposition();
cd.FileName = "download.zip";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
Response.BufferOutput = false;

return File(zipMemoryStream1, contentType);
```

Comment: (1/2) Your code using `ZipEntry` suggests you are using some 3rd-party library for ZIP compression. The ZIP file format can use two different text encodings for file names: 
"IBM Code Page 437" and "UTF-8". Perhaps that library you are using does not support "UTF-8" file names or need to be explicitly configured to do so. (Don't ask me how, because i don't know what library you are actually using here.)

Comment: (2/2) That said, why are you using a 3rd-party library at all instead of using the ZIP functionality provided by .NET itself? .NET's ZIP functionality supports UTF-8 file names and has no problems dealing with non-western file names. You find the related classes in the System.IO.Compression namespace.

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace can u please provide the implementation of how to create a file with the filename and data and add it into the zip as i am doing now?

Comment: The documentation for System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive already has an example implementation that demonstrates how to add an entry to a ZipArchive: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=net-6.0#examples

Answer (score 0):

my making the file.IsUnicodeText = true; this worked maybe the encoding in the file name after pushing entry in the zip .

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).